# How to check url is image or video?

Tags: ios, swift

I `fetch`  API response and parse  pick  url in swift  . but i need to check is **image** url or **video** url :

If i get image url then show image and if get video url then play video :

```
 if let url = postMedia?.url{

    //need to check here 
  }
```

For example

Here is my video url :

https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4
https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mov

here is image url :

https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.png
https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.jpg

note : i know how to show image and play video

Comment: You have to check extension of url 
NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath).pathExtension

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can check image like below

```
let url1 : String = "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"
        let imageExtensions = ["png", "jpg", "gif"]
        //...
        // Iterate & match the URL objects from your checking results
        let url: URL? = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: url1) as URL
        let pathExtention = url?.pathExtension
            if imageExtensions.contains(pathExtention!)
            {
                print("Image URL: \(String(describing: url))")
                // Do something with it
            }else
            {
               print("Movie URL: \(String(describing: url))")
            }
```

Same you can check for video

Comment: What if the url doesn't has an extension? Just like `https://sub.domain.com/video`.

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 3**

Hope will help you

```
extension String {
    public func isImageType() -> Bool {
        // image formats which you want to check
        let imageFormats = ["jpg", "png", "gif"]

        if URL(string: self) != nil  {

            let extensi = (self as NSString).pathExtension

            return imageFormats.contains(extensi)
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: i upvote you cause for write clean code but . why you extension String . it should be something like helper class .

Comment: Yes, you'r right both helper class and extension are used for reusability purpose. but in extension you can directly refer class type by self. so you have to no need to pass string in method argument .

Answer (score 3):

This answer asks the framework to check the filename extension.

```
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>

// ...

+ (BOOL) urlIsImage:(NSURL*)fileUrl
{
    if (fileUrl) {
        NSString *extension = fileUrl.pathExtension;
        if (extension && extension.length > 0) {
            CFStringRef uti = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, (__bridge CFStringRef)extension, NULL);
            return uti && UTTypeConformsTo(uti, kUTTypeImage);
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: The most reliable answer.

Answer (score 2):

Check The extension of the url by following code:

```
NSString *stringURL = @"http://...";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
NSString *path = [url path];
NSString *extension = [path pathExtension];
```

if your extension is mp4 or mov it is video else if it is jpg, jpeg,png etc , it will be image

Answer (score 2):

#### Swift

`import MobileCoreServices`

```
extension URL {
    func mimeType() -> String {
         let pathExtension = self.pathExtension
         if let uti = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, pathExtension as NSString, nil)?.takeRetainedValue() {
             if let mimetype = UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(uti, kUTTagClassMIMEType)?.takeRetainedValue() {
                return mimetype as String
             }
         }
         return "application/octet-stream"
    }

    var containsImage: Bool {
        let mimeType = self.mimeType()
        guard let uti = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassMIMEType, mimeType as CFString, nil)?.takeRetainedValue() else {
             return false
        }
        return UTTypeConformsTo(uti, kUTTypeImage)
    }

    var containsAudio: Bool {
        let mimeType = self.mimeType()
        guard let uti = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassMIMEType, mimeType as CFString, nil)?.takeRetainedValue() else {
              return false
        }
        return UTTypeConformsTo(uti, kUTTypeAudio)
    }
    var containsVideo: Bool {
        let mimeType = self.mimeType()
        guard  let uti = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassMIMEType, mimeType as CFString, nil)?.takeRetainedValue() else {
               return false
        }
        return UTTypeConformsTo(uti, kUTTypeMovie)
    }
 }
```

Comment: Hi Airza, how does this code look for iOS15 (i.e. Swift5.5) ?? (lots is deprecated)

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3**

Please try this one:

```
 extension String {

        public func isImage() -> Bool {
            // Add here your image formats.
            let imageFormats = ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif"]

            if let ext = self.getExtension() {
                return imageFormats.contains(ext)           
            }

            return false
        }

        public func getExtension() -> String? {
           let ext = (self as NSString).pathExtension

           if ext.isEmpty {
               return nil
           }

           return ext
        }

        public func isURL() -> Bool {
           return URL(string: self) != nil
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are sure that the file can only be a photo or a video you can use this simple code:

```
if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: YOUR_LOCAL_URL) {
    if let _: UIImage = UIImage(data: (data)) {
        print("image!")
    } else {
        print("video!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `import UniformTypeIdentifiers`

```swift
extension URL {
    var isImageFile: Bool {
        UTType(filenameExtension: pathExtension)?.conforms(to: .image) ?? false
    }
}
```