# how to detect if Firebase url is Photo or Video - Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, url, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I've been trying to figure how how to detect the `url` I retrieve from Firebase Storage is a Photo or a Video,

I followed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44843835/how-to-check-url-is-image-or-video) but it doesn't seem to work with Firebase Storage `URLs`.

The solution implemented in that question work **only** when the url has the `extension` at the end.
This is the code I implemented:

```
extension String {
public func isImageType() -> Bool {
    // image formats which you want to check
    let imageFormats = ["jpg", "png", "gif"]

    if URL(string: self) != nil  {

        let extensi = (self as NSString).pathExtension

        return imageFormats.contains(extensi)
    }
    return false
    }
}
```

To be clear, `URLs` retrieved from `Firebase` have this form.

**Photo** url example:

`https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myApp-1e48d.appspot.com/o/Images%2FD118DA58-C128-4E5E-BF24-AA820BEE5590.jpg?alt=media&token=49eie236-f9d1-45f8-bd0b-887382c61ccd`

**Video** url example:

`https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myApp-1e48d.appspot.com/o/Videos%2F1E4B7CA0-4D0E-4AC5-9856-2F59D0811C47.mp4?alt=media&token=615teacf-0d20-48aa-bb8f-cew84a14d76d`

As you can see the `extension` is not at the end (because there is the need of the token), hence the extension methods linked before doesn't work.

How can I still understand if the `url` retrieved from Firebase is of a Photo or a Video?

Comment: You can pretty easily remove the query string (everything after the question mark) and parse the extension from there. Or you can store the type of media along with the URL in whatever database you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply initialize an url with your link and get the path extension:

```
let link1 = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myApp-1e48d.appspot.com/o/Images%2FD118DA58-C128-4E5E-BF24-AA820BEE5590.jpg?alt=media&token=49eie236-f9d1-45f8-bd0b-887382c61ccd"

if let url = URL(string: link1) {
    let fileType = url.pathExtension  // "jpg"
}


let link2 = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myApp-1e48d.appspot.com/o/Videos%2F1E4B7CA0-4D0E-4AC5-9856-2F59D0811C47.mp4?alt=media&token=615teacf-0d20-48aa-bb8f-cew84a14d76d"

if let url = URL(string: link2) {
    let fileType = url.pathExtension  // "mp4"
}
```

Comment: Good call here but they're not storing the URL anywhere (as opposed to storing it in the database, which is usually how it's done); they're attempting to get all of the urls directly from Storage.

Comment: @Jay OP stated that the string is coming like this. Thats all he needs

Comment: Yeah - I was just trying to draw a bigger picture.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a code that works:

1. First `Remove all after "?"`:

   ```
   extension String {
   public func removeAfterExtension() -> String?{
    if let index = (self.range(of: "?")?.lowerBound){
        let beforeEqualsTo = String(self.prefix(upTo: index))
        return beforeEqualsTo
    }else{
        return self
       }
   }
   ```

Then check if it is `image Type`:

```
public func isImageType() -> Bool {
    // image formats which you want to check
    let imageFormats = ["jpg", "png", "gif"]

    if URL(string: self) != nil  {

        let extensi = (self as NSString).pathExtension

        return imageFormats.contains(extensi)
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: There's technically nothing wrong with this code. However. if the storage format changes, it could break. A better bet is to go with what Doug suggested in his comment. Simply store the filetype as another field along with the url - it will also be one less extension and less code.

Comment: I don't understand how to implement it, could you explain to me more in detail?
I get this url downloading from the Storage Reference, I don't understand how I could "store the filetype as another field along with the url "

Comment: This is an awful solution. Why not simply treat the string as an URL? Thats what it is.

Comment: @StackGU. There's your problem. You're relying on Storage for your URL. That's not how to do it. You need to store the path to the file in either Firebase Realtime Database or in Firestore when the file is written. See the [Upload a File](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#upload_from_a_local_file) section in the getting started guide. See where the upload function provides a `downloadURL` after the file is uploaded? Store *that* url in the database, along with the filetype.

Comment: @LeoDabus explain more

Comment: Just get the pathExtension from the URL check my post

Comment: @Jay no neet to store anything else. All OP needs is already on the url.

Comment: @StackGU When storing the url in the database (as shown in the guide) you also have the advantage of storing the filetype, an image name, the timestamp, which user posted it etc. You can approach it however works best but there are advantages of leveraging the database as well.

Comment: @Jay OP posted that his issue was trying to get the path extension from NSString. The solution is to get from the URL simple as that. Sure you can store the file type but that's not the issue here.

Comment: Thanks @Jay actually I was storing all that informations in Firestore document so the simple solution suggested by Leo Dabus seems to work fine